# What is the correct usage of DynamicParameters (Dapper) for a varbinary datatype?

Tags: dapper, dynamicparameters

A stored procedure returns, amongst other things, a varbinary(max) as an OUTPUT.  I can't understand how to access this information using Dapper.

Below is some cut-down sample code which illustrates the problem.  I supply some parameters to a StoredProcedure and I expect to get back a Photo which is stored as varbinary(max) on the SQL Server.

There is no DbType for varbinary.  I tried using DbType.Binary but this causes an exception in Dapper.  If I take the photo parameter away, all the other parameters I expect to get back (which are cut out of the sample for the sake of brevity) are working.  So the only issue is with retrieving the varbinary data.

What is the correct way to achieve this?

```
using (var connection = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection(HelperClassesBJH.HelperMethods.ConString("ProductionLocal")))
        {
            connection.Open();

            DynamicParameters p = new DynamicParameters();

            p.Add("@OpID", id, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);
            p.Add("@StageID", Properties.Settings.Default.StageID, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);               
            p.Add("@Photo", dbType: DbType.Binary, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);                

            try
            {
                connection.Execute(sql, p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

                op.Photo = p.Get<byte[]>("@Photo");                    
            }
            catch {}

        }
```

UPDATE:

I found that I have to supply the 'value' parameter in the DynamicParameters constructor.  This avoids the exception I was getting.  I am unable to understand why I need to supply a value, since the parameter is an output and the value I supply doesn't get used.  Here is the revised code:

```
DynamicParameters p = new DynamicParameters();
MemoryStream b = new MemoryStream();

p.Add("@OpID", id, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);
p.Add("@StageID", Properties.Settings.Default.StageID, DbType.Int32, ParameterDirection.Input);                
p.Add("@Photo", b, DbType.Binary, direction: ParameterDirection.Output);                

try
  {
     connection.Execute(sql, p, commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);

     op.Photo = p.Get<byte[]>("@Photo");
  }
 catch {}
```

This results in the retrieval of a byte array which contains the expected image data.

Answer (score 3):

You could try:

```
p.Add("@Photo", dbType: DbType.Binary, direction: ParameterDirection.Output, size: -1);
```

It seems to work for me locally, and that is how `varchar(max)` and `nvarchar(max)` are mapped (except as `DbType.AnsiString` and `DbType.String`, respectively), so it would be consistent.

Comment: My finding was that I had to supply 'object value' (it's in the DynamicParameters constructor), even though the parameter is an output and the value I supply does not get used.

Since I can't supply a byte[] value (don't know the length) I tried it with a MemoryStream object and it worked.  I can't display the image but the data in the byte array is present so perhaps that's a different issue.

I tried your method and I get the same exception as before.

Comment: @Q'' that's odd - I tried it locally with the exact code posted; what exception *exactly* are you seeing? (you never said)

Comment: I get the following exception: "Unable to cast object of type 'System.Int32' to type 'System.Byte[]'."

It occurs in:

at Dapper.DynamicParameters.Get[T](String name) in C:\projects\dapper\Dapper\DynamicParameters.cs:line 329

Comment: @Q'' something is very odd there; I put together a test rig with something that looks right (in terms of the proc etc), and it worked perfectly; are you sure you copied the line correctly? Sorry if that's a terrible question, but : it works perfectly over here

Comment: Thank you very much indeed for taking your own time to look at it @marc-gravell.  I copied the line correctly.  Maybe it's something to do with the SPROC end of things, I don't know.

Well, I've got it working perfectly for now by supplying the DynamicParameter constructor with a 'value' which doesn't get used! If I take that value back out, it goes back to the exception.  If I add size: -1 so that my line looks identical to yours, same exception.

Comment: @Q'' you could try using `Array.Empty<byte>()`, but... that might change the size down to 0, or it might accept the -1 specified separately; weird; I'd love to see a minimal repro, so I can try to fix it!